# What is this plant with dark green or red leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

What is the name of the following plant?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escallonia? but its not a house plant- certainly not in Europe, small ones are ok for a short period indoors but after a while they do need to be properly planted outdoors with plenty of room 1.5 meters².
I could be wrong only a guess...